# How do i mimic a WebBrowser with the HttpClient class?

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control, dotnet-httpclient

I noticed something interesting while I was working on my website earlier,
when I was on the website using my WebBrowser (Chrome) it said that 1 user was online on the page in my WordPress dashboard, which makes sense. I then closed the Web browser and navigated to my website using the Web Browser control in WPF, and obviously it said the same thing.

I then tried making a get request like so.

```
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        AllowAutoRedirect = true
    };

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134");
    var k = await client.GetAsync("https://website.com");
```

But when I did that it didn't react to it, so my question is..
How do I mimic the basics what a WebBrowser does to achieve the same thing.

I used Fiddler to see what happend and it looks like when I connect to a website using a browser it `Tunnels` to some `google-analytics.com` page with no more information.

I figured that's what `AllowAutoRedirect = true` would do but I guess not.

Comment: Postman or Insomnia. I would also try using chrome in Incognito Mode to disable any extensions that might be mucking things up

Comment: @TheBatman it's strange that it doesnt react to any get or post requests with Postman